# MySQL table structure with one row. Best handling for management and insertion

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, social-networking

I'm just creating a social network for practising my skills (PHP, HTML, CSS, JavaScript, etc.).
Now when designing the database layout a question appears, that I'm unhappily not able to solve.

I have a table called **UserMain**:

```
+------------+---------------------+
| Field      | Type                |
+------------+---------------------+
| u_id       | bigint(20) unsigned |
| u_email    | varchar(256)        |
| u_password | varchar(30)         |
| u_data     | varchar(25)         |
| u_friends  | varchar(28)         |
+------------+---------------------+
```

For storing the general data, that's being input when registering.

I wanted to separate the users data (prename, surename, sex, birthday, etc.) into another table called **data** and of course the relationship between users in a table called **friends**. So I decided to create a data- and friends-table for every user, via php using the u_id above and I came up with something like this, **[u_id]_data**:

```
+------------+---------------------+
| Field      | Type                |
+------------+---------------------+
| u_prename  | varchar(20)         |
| u_surname  | varchar(20)         |
| u_sex      | boolean             |
| u_birthday | DATE                |
| u_avatar   | varchar(28)         |
+------------+---------------------+
```

Now I don't want to attach value at the friends table, because the problem starts obviously with the [u_id]_data table. A user just has one pre- and surname, etc., so it is a 1-row-table. Now the question:

How do I handle the input of the table in relation to the [primary key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_key#Defining_primary_keys)?

For me, creating a new "id int not null auto_increment pk" seems needless for a single row, so I don't know what combination of columns to use for the primary key.

Maybe you know better implementations of this design, but please consider the following:

It doesn't matter what new implementation you have, the only thing I don't want to have is a table called **`data`** in which I have the data of all users.

Alright, I maybe have a bad opinion about MySQL or I'm not really good informed, but my idea of just having multiple data-tables comes from performance reasons.

My idea when changing or inserting data:

1. GetTheUsersId (Searching User-Table for the Id. That could take a
   littlebit if I would have ... let's say 10,000,000 users)
2. When having the [u_id] I just can use the data-table to find what I'm searching for.

With a table that is made up of (again) 10,000,000 rows it would take longer. Now don't start laughing as I'm taking the abstraction and dimensions to a level far away. It's just for supporting the idea of saving performance.

Comment: Whoa, back up a bit. You created a separate table for for every user?

Comment: Hm ... is it a bad idea? I thought MySql could handle 10.000 Tables easily, because it's just data, stored in different files and when searchen I just have to search the "user" table. Once I found the u_id I can easily access the data-table.

Comment: It's a terrible idea. MySQL can handle lots of tables, but that's not the point. Just have one user table, with all the users in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the only thing I don't want to have is a table called data in which I have the data of all users.

Please tell us more about why this is not an option? It's a perfectly valid way to store user data.

But to answer your question, you probably don't need any key at all if there is only one row in a table. You are going to refer to the row by the table name in most cases anyways:

```
SELECT * FROM [uid]_data ...
SELECT * FROM [uid]_data JOIN ...
UPDATE [uid]_data ...
INSERT INTO [uid]_data ...
DELETE FROM [uid]_data --You're probably going to want to DROP the table as well
```

Comment: I added the information in my question. Refering to the table with the tablename was also an idea I thought about. However a table has to have a pk, doesen't it?

Comment: @Hans123 It doesn't. The PK is useful in the standard approach to uniquely identify rows, but that's not the case in your schema. Also, a table with 10.000.000 rows doesn't necessarily mean that lookups will be slow. Databases are pretty smart when it comes to performance.

Comment: Also, see [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization-indexes.html) page for some info on indexes and how they help to optimize your table.